# Check password of encrypted Time Machine backup

Tags: macos, backup, encryption, time-machine

I have a Time Machine backup for my Macbook Pro that points to a Synology NAS drive on my network. The backup is encrypted, and I am pretty sure I know my password, but it's been so long since I set up the backup that I am starting to have doubts whether or not I know the correct password. Is there a way to test if I have the right access? I would rather not delete the backup and start a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out a way. You can unmount the Time Machine backup, and remount it. It will ask for your password again. Just know that if the password is incorrect, you won't be able to access any of those files.

Comment: Alternatively, you may remove the backup disk at the Time Machine Preferences pane, the re-add it. Select that you want to continue using the existing backup, then you will be prompted to re-enter the encryption password which will be verified.

Answer (score 4):

You might check application *Keychain Access* without affecting the existing backup.

- It should contain an entry which is named like your Computer and ends with *sparsebund*.
- It lives in Keychain *system*
- It is of type *application password*

Once the entry is found get its info and show its password. You will need your account's admin-password for this.

Comment: In my case, the name was not my computer name, but a long hexadecimal string, so better search for "sparsebundle" only.

Comment: I noticed something weird: my encryption password is 24 characters long, but the keychain entry displayed only the first 23 characters. Last character was missing!

Comment: I created a new backup image with a 22 characters password, and this one displayed in full. So there seems to be a length limit of 23. Weird, but perhaps useful to know.

Comment: @not2savvy I just tried and my 26-character password is shown fully in the keychain entry as well on macOS Monterey.